# Stringformat WPF with Date and additional string

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I want to format a Datetime in my textbox like this:
08.05.2018 12:18 Uhr

```
Text="{Binding CreationDate, StringFormat=dd.MM.yy hh:mm}"
```

This is what I've got until now, but the "Uhr" is missing.

Comment: `StringFormat=dd.MM.yy hh:mm U\\hr`, the double backslash escapes the format character `h`. IMO adding `Uhr` is antiquated, you'll easily notice that there is a time without it.

Comment: thank you :) you're right, I won't add "Uhr"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate,StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm U\\hr}"  />
```